# Bring up restart / shut-down dialog box using the keyboard

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, shutdown

Which keyboard short cut is there to bring up the restart / shut-down dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the  CTRL-ALT-DEL key combination i.e press Alt, Ctrl and Delete keys together. This will show the Shutdown Dialog with shutdown, restart and hibernate options.

Comment: thank you for pointing out such simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [this HowTo](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/) on defining custom hotkeys in Gnome. Using that info, create your hotkey with this as it's command: `gnome-session-save --shutdown-dialog`

Comment: http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/08/create-custom-desktop-shortcuts-in-ubuntu/ - You can follow this way as well to add custom shortcuts and add "gnome-session-save --shutdown-dialog".